# nginx tomcat7 ERROR : - “recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream”

Tags: java, spring, nginx, tomcat7

I am getting 2 types of error in my nginx logs.

> Error-1 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting
>   to upstream
>
> Error-2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading
>   response header from upstream

So my upstream is Tomcat7 and Nginx in the frontend.

I don't understand why am I getting this error. As, When I hit tomcat7 on 8080 port it works with a heavy load. But when hitting with high load on Nginx (running on port 80) which proxy's requests to tomcat7 fail with these 2 errors. All the answers I could get was of PHP-FPM but I am not using it. I have no clue how to fix.

EDITED : -

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {

 worker_connections 2000;
 multi_accept on;
 use epoll;
}
http {

 open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
 open_file_cache_valid 30s;
 open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
 open_file_cache_errors on;
 reset_timedout_connection on;
 client_body_timeout 200s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
 client_header_timeout 200s;

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##

 sendfile on;
 tcp_nopush on;
 tcp_nodelay on;
 keepalive_timeout 9000;
 keepalive_requests 100000;
 types_hash_max_size 2048;
 proxy_connect_timeout 16000s;
 proxy_send_timeout 16000s;
 proxy_read_timeout 16000s;
 send_timeout 16000s;

 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;
 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

 gzip on;
 gzip_disable "msie6";

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}




# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
upstream _tomcat-stream-beta {

 server 127.0.0.1:8080;
 keepalive 500000;
}
server {

 #recursive_error_pages on;
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name 127.0.0.1;
 #docshare Root WebSite
 root /usr/share/nginx/www/;
 #  error_page 500 502 503 504 =200 /api/testing/errorHandle?headers=$http_attributes;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/stream.error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.access.log;
 client_body_in_file_only on;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;

 location ~ /.well-known {

  allow all;
 }

 location @tomcat-stream-beta {

  proxy_pass http://_tomcat-stream-beta;
 }
 location ^~ / {

  proxy_pass http://_tomcat-stream-beta;
  proxy_read_timeout 600000s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 600000s;
  proxy_send_timeout 600000s;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
 }
}
```

Comment: Post your nginx config. use `nginx -T` and post the output of that as the config

Comment: Hi Tarun, Edited my question you can view my "nginx -T" result.

Comment: Your timeouts are way too high. Lower them to something like 90, 120, 150, 180  and try your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following configuration : -

1. We had to speed up our internal code i.e. code Execution time. Now each request is taking less than 50 ms.
2. Nginx configuration used is : -

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout 200s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
    client_header_timeout 200s;

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 900;
    keepalive_requests 10000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    #proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1600;
    proxy_send_timeout 1600;
    proxy_read_timeout 1600;
    send_timeout 1600;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/stream.error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```